# javascript send another element for this parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 input elements and and both have onblur event handler which sends 'this' as parameter.

Existing HTML:

```
<input id="amt1" onblur="work(this);" />
<input id="amt2" onblur="work(this);" />
```

I need to call the onblur event of the 2nd input element also in 1st input element onblur. But I cannot modify the 'work' function. So I tried the the below code and it didn't work.

Tried HTML:

```
<input id="amt1" onblur="work(this);work(document.getElementById('amt2'));" />
<input id="amt2" onblur="work(this);" />
```

Is there any way to make it work or should I have to rewrite the work function as new function for this purpose.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? sorry i do not get it. You want to type something in `amt2` and then in `amt1` onblur get `amt2` value ?

Comment: I am curious why you can not modify work function you can pass multiple augments to one function.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I cannot modify the work function because it has been used in many places and it also has other complicated logics which I don't want to mess up. What I want to do is trigger the onblur event of the 2nd element when the onblur event of the 1st element is triggered. And I know I can just create a new replica function of the work function to work for just this scenario but it will take a lot of time. I have found a solution myself and I have answered this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input id="amt1" onblur="(function(){work(this); otherFunc();})(event)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function newFunc() {
  var newId = document.getElementById('amt2')
  console.log(newId)
}
```

```html
<input id="amt1" onblur="work(this);newFunc();" />
<input id="amt2" onblur="work(this);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just focus and blur the 2nd input element on the 1st element's onblur with:

```
<input id = "amt1" onblur = "work(this); document.getElementById('amt2').focus(); document.getElementById('amt2').blur();" />
<input id="amt2" onblur="work(this);" />
```